# Загрузка картинок в doc файл

Tags: doc, delphi, изображения

У меня имеется большое количество текста в тексотвых файлах.
Требуется через Delphi, заменить текст на картинки, то есть каждый символ заменить на определенную картинку и  ввести эти картинки в .doc файл.

Возможно ли вообще такое?

Как записать компонент image в doc?

Answer (score 2):

Вполне возможно.

Через OLE

Разбейте свою задачу на этапы:

1 Открыть документ Word через Delphi

2 Получить текст из активного документа Word

3 Вставить картинку в Word

Линк для пункта 1 и 2 [Создать из Delphi документ MS Word](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/create_word_doc.html)

Линк для пункта 3 [Image Delphi Word](http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=81405)